# Plotting concave shape (lens focus) using mplot3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am currently trying to visualize the focal shape of a lens using matplotlib, specifically the mplot3d toolbox. I obtained the data from fitting ellipses to a set of microscope images at different focal lengths as major `major` and minor `minor` radius, as well as the rotation angle `ang` of said ellipses. From this, I'm generating `x`, `y` and `z` arrays containing the coordinates of the ellipses like this.

```
i = 100
omega = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, i, endpoint=True)

x = [major * np.cos(omega) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang + 90)) - minor * np.sin(omega) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang + 90)) for major, minor, ang in zip(maj_avg, min_avg, ang_avg)]
y = [major * np.cos(omega) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang + 90)) + minor * np.sin(omega) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang + 90)) for major, minor, ang in zip(maj_avg, min_avg, ang_avg)]
z = [np.full(i, zi) for zi in zs]
```

If I now plot the individual ellipses in 3D space, everything works as intended.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for x_arr, y_arr, z_arr in zip(x, y, z):
    ax.plot(x_arr, y_arr, z_arr)

plt.show()
```

[image: Lines plot of ellipses]

What I am trying to do is generate a surface plot from this dataset which shows the focal shape of the lens. Up to now, I tried `plot_surface` together with `meshgrid`/`griddata` like this:

```
xi = np.arange(-300, 300, 0.1)
yi = np.arange(-300, 300, 0.1)

xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
zgrid = griddata(np.ravel(x), np.ravel(y), np.ravel(z), xi, yi, interp='linear')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(xgrid, ygrid, zgrid)
plt.show()
```

[image: Surface plot of dataset using griddata]

And also `plot_trisurf` is giving similarly unsatisfactory results:

```
triang = mtri.Triangulation(np.ravel(x), np.ravel(y))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(triang, np.ravel(z), cmap=plt.cm.CMRmap)
plt.show()
```

[image: Surface plot of dataset using trisurf]

Could someone suggest a way to properly show the high-z region of my dataset in the surface plots?

Comment: If you have an issue like that, first create a [mcve]. Here the problem is that you are trying to interpolate a parametric curve on a grid. Is there any reason for that? Why not take the data points themselves?

Comment: Could your problem be that due to interpolation there are NaN values in the border region? See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48639898/8881141).

Comment: @Piinthesky No the problem is simply that when trying to interpolate a non-bijective, non-sujective function on a grid you will inevitably get a [complete mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSPnI.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to interpolate a parametric curve on a grid. Since the shape to draw is  a non-bijective, non-sujective one, you get a complete mess.

[image]

Instead of trying to interpolate the points you may directly plot them.

```
X = np.array(x)
Y = np.array(y)
Z = np.array(z)
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap="RdYlBu")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Complete example for reproduction:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

maj_avg = 50*(np.linspace(0,1,20)-0.6)**2+50
min_avg = 60*(np.linspace(0,1,20)-0.7)**2+60
ang_avg = np.linspace(0,90,20)
zs = np.arange(0,40,2)

i = 100
omega = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, i, endpoint=True)

x = [major * np.cos(omega) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang + 90)) \
     - minor * np.sin(omega) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang + 90)) \
     for major, minor, ang in zip(maj_avg, min_avg, ang_avg)]
y = [major * np.cos(omega) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang + 90)) \
     + minor * np.sin(omega) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang + 90)) \
     for major, minor, ang in zip(maj_avg, min_avg, ang_avg)]
z = [np.full(i, zi) for zi in zs]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
#for x_arr, y_arr, z_arr in zip(x, y, z):
#    ax.plot(x_arr, y_arr, z_arr)

X = np.array(x)
Y = np.array(y)
Z = np.array(z)
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap="RdYlBu")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. I guess I didn't try that because in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots), it says that X, Y, and Z have to be provided as 2D array, which I assumed I would only get by using griddata.